# How to get is_active = False in Django Shell from models?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have to get data in the Django shell which has an attribute is_active=false, but trying to filter against this parameter returns an empty queryset.

```py
queryset = model.objects.filter(is_active=False)
queryset.count() # returns 0
```

Comment: There is no reason this would not work. Are you sure one of your items has active set to False? What is returned by `model.objects.filter(is_active=False).count()`?

Comment: Yes, I have 617 items that have is_active = false.  model.objects.filter(is_active=False).count() this returning 0. In model I am using StatusMixin.

Comment: Ah my bad I made a typo, I wanted to ask what was returned by `model.objects.exclude(is_active=False).count()`